# .NET 4.0: Executing network assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, caspol

Today, we upgraded our application to .NET framework 4.0.
As it calls an assembly residing on a network share, for the previous version we needed the following command:

```
 caspol.exe -m -chggroup 1.3 -zone "Intranet" FullTrust
```

For .NET 4, we read about the "NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy" and included it with out App.config file.

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work: As soon as our application starts up, we get an exception stating that we cannot access environment variables (System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission missing).

We played with CasPol.exe, but were unable to figure out what we have to do in order to allow our application to access the environment variables. Removing the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable calls still does not solve the problem - it seems a lot of other operations won't work, too.

Removing the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy switch (or setting it to false) allows us to read the environment again, but (of course) prevents the execution of the assembly on the network share.

Here is our complete App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="Launcher.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Launcher.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Executable" serializeAs="String">
                <value>\\office\client\client-8919\Client.exe</value>
            </setting>
        </Launcher.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:

This is the code we use for launching the assembly residing on the network share:

```
    public void ExecuteFile(string version, string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String appPath = GetExecutablePath();
            if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
                throw new Exception("cache does not contain expected executable directory: " + appPath);

            String executable = appPath + "\\Client.exe";
            if (!File.Exists(executable))
                throw new Exception("cache does not contain expected executable: " + executable);

            if (Program.DEBUG_MODE)
                MessageBox.Show("App Path: " + appPath + "\r\nExecutable: " + executable);

            AppDomainSetup domainInfo = new AppDomainSetup();
            domainInfo.ApplicationBase = appPath;
            AppDomain subDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Name", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, domainInfo);

            subDomain.ExecuteAssembly(executable, subDomain.Evidence, args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Ausführen der Version im lokalen Cache!\r\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any tweaking - one of the changes for .NET 4 was that [all local intranet applications are granted full trust by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx)

Comment: We had success with passing `null` as evidence to the `CreateDomain` call and using the `ExecuteAssembly` overload that doesn't require an `evidence ` parameter. Given the values for evidence you pass, the result should be the same.

Comment: Christian, thanks a lot! Your tip did the trick. Maybe you could just copy your text as an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: Damien, thank you very much for your comment. You are right, using Christian's modification (passing in null as evidence) we do not need any tweaking like these configuration options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a "good" answer, sorry. But we had success with passing `null` as evidence to the `CreateDomain` call and using the `ExecuteAssembly` overload that doesn't require an `evidence` parameter. Given the values for evidence you pass, the result should be the same.